# Connection Error PHP with SQL server 2012

Tags: php, sql, connection

I'm facing an issue in connection PHP with SQL server 2012. Configured and (.dll) files and configured them.

In SQL server management studio i create a database named it "helloworld". My SQL server authentication mode is window.

The issue is connection established on system database like "master,msdb" but the database i created. It says:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "helloworld" requested by the login. The login failed.

The code I'm using is:

```
$serverName = "(local)"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"master","ReturnDatesAsStrings" => false,"CharacterSet" => 'utf-8');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";                
}else{
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";                                
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. I just need to make a connection with the database i created not the system database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass') or  DIE ('Not Connected');
 mysql_select_db("example") or die('Not Connected');

echo "successful" ;

Comment: Hi it's not related to mysql i said i'm using it for SQL server.